# How can I make a primary key consisting of two foreign keys, 'be the same key', whatever order the values are?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to set up a backend with a friend system, where users can send each other friend requests and become friends etc.

To achieve this, I have made a Friendship-table with a primary key (User1Id, User2Id). User1Id will always be the user who first sent a friend request.

How can I make my database treat the primary keys so that an entry with primary key (123, 456) will be the same key as (456, 123) ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL. With Entity Framework Core (However I can probably figure out the migration part myself :) )

Comment: You can't. but you can prevent psudo duplicates like this using a simple check constraint.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: you could also add a [Trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) to the table and manually check if such a pseudo duplicate exists. (if it´s about preventing the insert for the second `456`, `123` input).

Comment: "User1Id will always be the user who first sent a friend request." - So there is a meaning to the order of the values - meaning that `(123, 456)` is different then `(456, 123)`...

Comment: One (of several) ways to do this is to have a convention, enforced by a check constraint, that User1Id < User2Id, and have a separate column that indicates which user initiated the request.  This convention potentially makes it easier to search for connections: if you want to know if X and Y are connected, where X < Y, you search for a single primary key {X, Y} rather than searching for both {X,Y} and {Y,X}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to actual columns `User1Id, User2Id` you can create two persisted computed columns and make those columns a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SortedID1]  AS (case when [ID1]<[ID2] then [ID1] else [ID2] end) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [SortedID2]  AS (case when [ID1]<[ID2] then [ID2] else [ID1] end) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SortedID1] ASC,
    [SortedID2] ASC
))
```

In the example above the column `SortedID1` is minimum of values of `ID1` and `ID2`, `SortedID2` is maximum. So, the pair `SortedID1, SortedID2` is always `(123, 456)` regardless of how you enter these values in `ID1` and `ID2`.